# Sitecore personalisation - DropLink

Tags: sitecore, personalization, sitecore-dms

Not fully used personalisaiton yet, so have what I hope is an easy question.
My page is setup where users can use a droplink to pick content for 3 "slots" on the homepage, from a "bucket" of available content items that can appear.

I want to use a "rule" to show different items in each slot, depending on if the rule is met or not, but I can't seem to work out where I set this.

Right now, my page editor view is broken (currently have an open ticket with Sitecore for work out why this is), so I am hoping this can be done from the content editor.

I have already ticked the "Show the Personalization Section" under Application Options.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a conditional rendering rule that you're wanting to create.  If that is the case, unless you want to apply the rule to ALL renderings (which I wouldn't recommend), you would create the rule under 
System -> Marketing Center -> Personalization -> Rules. Here you can set up a conditional rendering rule that will check conditions and then do something.  Since this is going to apply to presentation, the actions are limited. Mostly to presentation.

Now to apply that, you go to the layout details on the item or the  standard values for the item template.  When you click on the rendering (like you would to set a data source), it brings you to the edit screen and you should be able to scroll down to the Personalization section.  If your rule is not in the list, then it's most likely in the wrong place.  Anyway, if it's there, you simply put a check next to that box and it will now apply that rule when figuring out the layout details when the item is rendered.